# Problema de apuntadores en POO c++

Tags: c++, poo, punteros, opengl

Resulta que estoy trabajando con clases en open gl, programe una matriz de modelado en la clase operador intentto mandar un apuntador a mis demas clases (de la clase operador) pero siempre me aparece este error

"expected identifier before '&' token"

Alguien alguna idea de por que no funciona por favor :c de antemano muchas gracias

```
#define ESCENARIO_H

#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Prisma.h"
#include "Piramide.h"
#include "Casa.h"
#include "Camioneta.h"
#include "Carro.h"
#include "Arbol.h"
#include "Cilindro.h"
#include "Sol.h"
#include "Nube.h"
#include "Operador.h"
class Escenario
{
    public:
        Escenario();
        virtual ~Escenario();

    private:
        Operador opera;
        Prisma cubo1;
        Piramide piramide1;
        Casa casa_base(&opera);
    Camioneta camioneta1(&opera);
    Carro carro1(&opera);
    Arbol arb(&opera);
    Cilindro cilin(&opera);
    Sol sol(&opera);
    Nube nub(&opera);

};

#endif // ESCENARIO_H
```

Comment: Los argumentos de las funciones se declaran `tipo nombre`: `Casa casa_base( Operador * );`. Por favor, revisa **lo mínimo** del lenguaje, hay miles de tutoriales disponibles.

Comment: Em... bueno tal vez estoy entendiendo mal, pero estoy tratando de mandar un apuntador a mi objeto opera de tipo operador a los constructores de mis otros obejtos, no se a que te refieres con "tipo nombre" por lo que entiendo tu crees que esas son funciones pero son objetos.

Comment: Yo no creo nada. Es lo que has puesto en el código. Declaras una clase de nombre `Escenario`, y, en su parte privada, declaras funciones-miembro que devuelven cosas y esperan argumentos. Si ni siquiera es eso lo que quieres hacer ...